# How can I execute a shell script from stdin and get the output in realtime using python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to mimic the below using python subprocess:

```
cat /tmp/myscript.sh | sh
```

The /tmp/myscript.sh contains:

```
ls -l
sleep 5
pwd
```

Behaviour: stdout shows the result of "ls" and the results of "pwd" are shown after 5 seconds.

What I have done is:

```
import subprocess      
f = open("/tmp/myscript.sh", "rb")
p = subprocess.Popen("sh", shell=True, stdin=f, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
f.close()
p.stdout.read()
```

This waits until ALL the processing is done and shows the results all at once. The desired effect is to fill in the stdout pipe in realtime.

*Note: This expectation seems non sense but this is sample from a bigger and complex situation which I cannot describe here.*

*Another Note: I can't use p.communicate. This whole thing is inside a select.select statement so I need stdout to be in a pipe.*

Comment: Rather than `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, have you tried putting something there that prints console output directly? Otherwise, yes, you only get results when you run `p.stdout.read()`... Also, _"useless use of cat"_ - just do `sh script.sh`, or `chmod +x script.sh`, and execute the script directly...

Comment: As I say in the Note, this is a heavy simplified version of what I need to achieve. I need the sh execute code from stdin only. And from memory, not from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you don't give an argument to `read()`, it reads until EOF, which means it has to wait until the subprocess exits and the pipe is closed.

If you call it with a small argument it will return immediately after it has read that many characters

```
import subprocess      
f = open("/tmp/myscript.sh", "rb")
p = subprocess.Popen("sh", shell=True, stdin=f, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
f.close()
while True:
    c = p.stdout.read(1)
    if not c:
        break
    print(c, end='')
print()
```

Note that some many buffer their output when `stdout` is connected to a pipe, so this might not solve the problem for everything. The shell doesn't buffer its own output, but `ls` probably does. But since `ls` is producing all its output at once, it won't be a problem in this case.

To solve the more general problem you may need to use a pty instead of a pipe. The `pexpect` library is useful for this.

Comment: Thank was really quick! Indeed the read function was the problem. I will use os.read instead. Thank you very much!